# history.back() without page refresh in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I was working on MVC3 with Telerik controls. My requirement is something like this:

I have grid filtering, sorting functionalities. After Filtering the grid looks something different from the initial page loads grid. After Filtering has happened, User navigates to next page. After navigation the user thinking to go back to the previous grid filtered page.

So I need to preserve the page to load again to show the grid. So I need functionality to go back to the previous page without page refreshing. I have tried **history.back()** && **history.go(-1)**. But It's not working with IE. Is there any feature available in Javascript or Jquery to make this possible. Pls let me know the feature.

Answer (score 0):

ie<10 don't support `HTML5 history` API
have a look at this http://caniuse.com/#search=history
it gives information about what all features are supported
with it you can use a javascript library [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detected which HTML5 features are supported at run time